# RavenDB - stream index query results in exception

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

We're currently trying to use the `Task<IAsyncEnumerator<StreamResult<T>>> StreamAsync<T>(IQueryable<T> query, CancellationToken token = null)`, running into some issues.

Our document look something like:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Geolocation Geolocation { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<string> SubEntities { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
      this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      this.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

In combination we've a view model, which is also the model were indexing:

```
public class EntityViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Geolocation Geolocation { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; set; }
}
```

And ofcourse, the index, with the resulttype inheriting from the viewmodel, to enable that SubEntities are mapped and output correctly, while enabling the addition of searchfeatures such as fulltext etc.:

```
public class EntityWithSubentitiesIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Entity, EntityWithSubentitiesIndex.Result>
{
    public class Result : EntityViewModel
    {
         public string Fulltext { get; set; }
    }

    public EntityWithSubentitiesIndex ()
    {
        Map = entities => from entity in entities
                select new
                {
                    Id = entity.Id,
                    Created = entity.Created,
                    Geolocation = entity.Geolocation,
                    SubEntities = entity.SubEntities.Select(x => LoadDocument<SubEntity>(x)),
                    Fulltext = new[]
                    {
                        entity.Description
                    }.Concat(entity.SubEntities.Select(x => LoadDocument<SubEntity>(x).Name)),
                    __ = SpatialGenerate("__geolokation", entity.Geolocation.Lat, entity.Geolocation.Lon)
                };

            Index(x => x.Created.Date, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            Index(x => x.Fulltext, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            Spatial("__geolokation", x => x.Cartesian.BoundingBoxIndex());
        }
}
```

Finally we're querying like this:

```
var query = _ravenSession.Query<EntityWithSubentitiesIndex.Result, EntityWithSubentitiesIndex>()
                .Customize(c =>
                {
                    if (filter.Boundary == null) return;

                    var wkt = filter.Boundary.GenerateWkt().Result;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wkt))
                    {
                        c.RelatesToShape("__geolokation", wkt, SpatialRelation.Within);
                    }
                })
                .AsQueryable();

// (...) and several other filters here, removed for clarity

var enumerator = await _ravenSession.Advanced.StreamAsync(query);

var list = new List<EntityViewModel>(); 
while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
{
    list.Add(enumerator.Current.Document);
}
```

When doing so we're getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The query results type is 'Entity'
>   but you expected to get results of type 'Result'. If you want to
>   return a projection, you should use
>   .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto() (for Query) or
>   .SelectFields() (for DocumentQuery) before calling to
>   .ToList().

According to the documentation, the Streaming API should support streaming via an index, and querying via an IQueryable at once.

How can this be fixed, while still using an index, and the streaming API, to:

1. Prevent having to page through the normal query, to work around the default pagesize
2. Prevent having to load the subentities one at a time when querying

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nicolai-heilbuth stated in the comments to @jens-pettersson's answer, it seems to be a bug in the RavenDB client libraries from version 3 onwards.

Bug report filed here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-3916

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
.As<Entity>()
```

(or `.OfType<Entity>()`)  in your query. That should work in the regular stream.

This is a simple streaming query using "TestIndex" that is an index over an entity `Test` and I'm using a `TestIndex.Result` to look like your query. *Note that this is actually not what the query will return, it's only there so you can write typed queries (ie. `.Where(x => x.SomethingMapped == something)`)*

```
var queryable = session.Query<TestIndex.Result, TestIndex>()
                        .Customize(c =>
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        })
                        .As<Test>();

var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(queryable);

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var entity = enumerator.Current.Document;
}
```

If you instead want to retrieve the values from the **index** and not the actual entity being indexed you have to store those as fields and then project them into a "view model" that matches your mapped properties. This can be done by using `.ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` in your query. All the stored fields from the index will be mapped to the model you specify.

Hope this helps (and makes sense)!

Edit: Updated with a, for me, working example of the Streaming API used with `ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` that returns more than 128 records.

```
using (var session = store.OpenAsyncSession())
{
    var queryable = session.Query<Customers_ByName.QueryModel, Customers_ByName>()
        .Customize(c =>
        {
            //just to do some customization to look more like OP's query
            c.RandomOrdering();
        })
        .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<CustomerViewModel>();

    var enumerator = await session.Advanced.StreamAsync(queryable);

    var customerViewModels = new List<CustomerViewModel>();
    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        customerViewModels.Add(enumerator.Current.Document);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(customerViewModels.Count); //in my case 504
}
```

The above code works great for me. The index has one property mapped (name) and that property is stored. This is running the latest stable build (3.0.3800).

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your answer. 

We're using `ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` when using the normal paged queries, which works flawlessly. The problem is, when I put `ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` on the query in combination with the Streaming API, then it's for some reason going back to being bound to 128 results again.

Comment: @JackieNagel Very weird. I've updated my answer with a query that uses the Streaming API in combination with `ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<T>()` and that returns more than 128 results...

Comment: It's indeed very weird. Thanks a lot for your input, but unfortunately none of it works, still receiving a maximum of 128 docs.

I had a hunch it might be the RavenDB version, but after upgrade of server and client it's still the same. I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: It seems like it puts a pagesize of 128 on the request towards Raven, which is quite unfortunate, but explains why it doesn't work :-/

Comment: It seems that the pagesize of 128 is introduced by the c.RelatesToShape() call. Using the c.RandomOrdering() from the above example, it returns more than 128 results. Using RelatesToShape it only returns 128.

Comment: TLDR; Check the "Edit" section of this answer.

Note: According to docs, `OfType` and `As` are client side projection.
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/querying/projections